# having trouble while deploying rails code with capistrano on aws ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

✔ 01 deploy@52.77.210.241 2.221s
00:23 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 NoMethodError: undefined method `reject' for #<String:0x0055d30daf90e8>
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:64:in`global_configuration'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in `configuration'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in`each'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in `load'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro.rb:23:in`load'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/rails/railtie.rb:5:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in`call'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hoo…
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in`block in ru…
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`run_load_ho…
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:149:in `run_load_hooks!'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:93:in`instance'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails.rb:37:in `application'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/releases/20161206071417/Rakefile:6:in`'
      01 /home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/bundle:23:in`load'
      01 /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@52.77.210.241: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method`reject' for #
/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:64:in `global_configuration'
/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:32:in`configuration'
/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:42:in `each'
/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/application.rb:36:in`load'
/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro.rb:23:in `load'
/home/deploy/contactbook/shared/bund

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure if Figaro Gem uploads the application.yml settings to the production server, that's why you have to create the application.yml file who will be stored on ***shared/config/*** folder.